# Create a Star Pattern in Java.

Tags: java, for-loop

I am working on a simple star pattern program in Java. I have the code running but it is not doing what it's supposed to. My code is:

```
public class q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--){
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--){
                System.out.print("*");              
            }           
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 $$$$$$$$$$
 $$$$$$$$$
 $$$$$$$$
 $$$$$$$
 $$$$$$
 $$$$$
 $$$$
 $$$
 $$
 $
```

**What I want is something like this below:**

```
         $
        $$
       $$$
      $$$$
     $$$$$
 ..........
 $$$$$$$$$$
```

Can someone please help me figure out how I would get the above pattern. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int length = 10;

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {

        //Print spaces first
        for (int j = length - 1; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Then print "*"
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output is for `length = 10` :

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
  ******
 *******
********
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this pattern using a single `for` loop:

```
char [] mirrorascval = new char[5];
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
            mirrorascval[i] ='*';
            System.out.println(mirrorascval);
        }
```

Comment: please explain what your code does to help other users

Comment: By using single for loop we can achieve this pattern

Comment: Sorry - I mean please edit your answer to include your explanation, e.g. see my edit

Comment: Thank you..next time I will take care of it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
class StarTriangle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 8; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      } 
      for (k = 8; k >= i; k--) {
          System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void starPrint(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class firstStar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=S.nextInt();
        int i=1;
        while(i<=n) {
            int j=1;
            while(j<=i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                j=j+1;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i=i+1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *
**
***
****
*****
******

Answer (score 0):

```
package star.pattern;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StarPattern {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
        int l;
        System.out.print("Enter No Of Line You Want:- ");
        l=scn.nextInt();
        int x=1;
        while(x<=l){
           int j=x;
            while(j<l){
                System.out.print(" ");
                j++;
            }
            int y=1;
            while(y<=x){
                System.out.print("*");
                y++;
            }
           System.out.println("");
           x++;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            for (int j = 10; j >= i; j--){
                System.out.print("*");              
            }           
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your answer improve upon the 7 other answers that have been posted over the last 4 years?

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
    int i, j, k=8;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        k = k - 2;
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
```